# How to get the value of a appended variable jQuery

Tags: jquery

apologize in advanced if I am not explaining my self very clearly. What I believe I need to do and please steer me in the right direction if I am wrong but I am trying to capture the total value of an appended variable.

HTML

```
 <input type="number" id="startingAmt" placeholder="Start Amount">
<input type="number" id="billAmt" placeholder="Bill Amount">
<button id="addBtn">Add</button>
<h4>
    Ending Amount: <i class="fa fa-usd"></i> 
    <span id="endingAmt">0</span>
  </h4>
  <ul id="myList">

  </ul
```

How it works: Input a number into the #startingAmt input, and a number into the #billAmt input. Click add to append an li to the ul. Whatever is in the #billAmt input is placed into the li when you click the #addBtn.

JS (keep in mind this is all one file for testing purposes)

```
    $('#addBtn').on("click", function() {
    var startingAmt = parseInt($('#startingAmt').val()) || 0;
    var billAmt = ($('#billAmt').val());
    var inputAmt = billAmt;
    var inputAmtTotal = 0;

    $('#myList').append("<li>" + billAmt + "</li>");

    $(inputAmt).each(function(){
        inputAmtTotal += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;  

        $(endingAmt).text(inputAmtTotal - inputAmt);
    });

});
```

So im wondering how I can get the total value of each billAmt that is appended.
I set billAmt = to the value or input of the #billAmt input then set the variable billAmt to = the inputAmt variable. The li is appended with the value of the billAmt. Then I perform a loop to capture each inputAmt or so I think and than the total will be dynamically calculated and display and replace the '0' next to the ending Amt. I can get it to work as a one time calculation but how can I get the total value of each inputAmt? The ending Amount should be startingAmt - inputAmtTotal where inputAmtTotal = the total of the inputAmt.

I thought at first once I append the li with the billAmt value the li's value would become that number but that does not seem to be the case when testing it in the DOM. Maybe there is a way for the li to inherite the billAmt value so I can than perform a loop on all of the lis?

Please advise is this is even possible how I have it or if there is a better approach to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/s9tujLwf/17/

You need to loop each li, get its value, sum those together, and then take that total away from your starting amount to get how much you have left.

```
var runningTotal = 0; // the total of all li's 
var startingAmount = $("#startingAmt").val(); // the left field

$("#myList li").each(function(){
    runningTotal += parseInt($(this).text());
});

$("#endingAmt").text(startingAmount - runningTotal); // how much you have left
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much that works! I appreciate you! I tried to upvote but im not high enough rank :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this

```
var listItems = $('#myList li');
var i, sum = 0;

listItems.each(function() {
   sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work I think.

```
var allLi = $('#myList li');
var sumOfLi = 0;
for(var i=0; i<allLi.length; i++){
  sumOfLi = sumOfLi + $(allLi[i]).text()*1;
}
```

Comment: Trying to sum up with text will not yield correct answer - items with `100` & `200` will yield `100200`

Comment: @NafiulIslam use $(allLi[i]).text()*1;